# Achartengine Barchart with labels above each bar (Horizontal Bars)

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

I am new in using the achartengine library for android, please bear with me. I want my horizontal barchart to have labels above each bar. I tried to manipulate the renderers and searched for solutions, but with no luck at this time. 
**Here is my desired output:**

[image]

**So far here is my code for creating the barchart:**

public GraphicalView getChartView(Context context) {
    int x = 8000, y = 4000, z = 0;

```
CategorySeries series1 = new CategorySeries("Bar1");
CategorySeries dummySeries = new CategorySeries("Bar dummy");
CategorySeries series2 = new CategorySeries("Bar2");

series1.add(x);
dummySeries.add(z);
series2.add(y);
XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataSet = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset(); 
dataSet.addSeries(series1.toXYSeries()); 
dataSet.addSeries(dummySeries.toXYSeries());
dataSet.addSeries(series2.toXYSeries());


XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer(); 
renderer.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(
        R.color.barchart_green));

renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
renderer.setChartValuesSpacing(60);
renderer.setLineWidth((float) 10.5d);
renderer.setChartValuesTextSize(context.getResources().getDimension(
        R.dimen.salesquota_axis_textsize));

XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer(); 
renderer2.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(
        R.color.barchart_orange));

renderer2.setChartValuesSpacing(60);
renderer2.setLineWidth((float) 10.5d);
renderer2.setDisplayChartValues(true);
renderer2.setChartValuesTextSize(context.getResources().getDimension(
        R.dimen.salesquota_axis_textsize));

XYSeriesRenderer dummyRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer(); 
dummyRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);

dummyRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(false);
dummyRenderer.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 10.5d);
dummyRenderer.setLineWidth((float) 10.5d);

XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(); 
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(dummyRenderer);
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);
// mRenderer.setXTitle("xValues");

mRenderer.setShowLegend(true);
mRenderer.setShowLabels(false);
mRenderer.setShowAxes(false);

mRenderer.addXTextLabel(0, "Quota");
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Sales status");



mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
mRenderer.setShowGrid(false);
mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
mRenderer.setBarWidth(context.getResources().getDimension(
        R.dimen.salesquota_barwidth));

mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
mRenderer.setXAxisMax(4);

mRenderer.setYAxisMax(10000);
mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
mRenderer.setMarginsColor(context.getResources()
        .getColor(R.color.White));

mRenderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);


mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context, dataSet, mRenderer,
        Type.DEFAULT);

return mChartView;
```

}

**Then i added the returned mChartView into my LinearLayout:**

```
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) myFragmentView
                .findViewById(R.id.salesquota_layout);
        SalesStackedBarChart barChartStacked = new SalesStackedBarChart();
        layout.addView(barChartStacked.getChartView(getActivity()));
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Horizontal bars are experimental in AChartEngine. See: https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=203&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary

Comment: Thanks, ill try this out sir. I will let you know if it works.